# How to translate the text label in angular material mat-button using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-translate

I am using angular material components example mat-menu mat-button and using ngx-translate to translate the labels in my application. But all other elements of html is getting translated but using angular material classes like mat-button and mat-tabs ngx-translate is not working. Please help in this

I have tried the following things in my code.

This is my html file where i am using [translate] directive.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="file" [hidden]="isFullScreen" [translate] = "'FILE.MENU_FILE'" #matformbutton = "matButton" >{{fileMenu.name}}</button>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="edit" [hidden]="isFullScreen" [translate] = "'EDIT.MENU_EDIT'" #matformbutton = "matButton">{{editMenu.name}}</button>
  <button mat-button [hidden]="isFullScreen" [translate] = "'VIEW.MENU_VIEW'" #matformbutton= "matButton">{{viewMenu.name}}</button>
```

and my component.ts file

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

declare var $ :any;

constructor( public translateService: TranslateService) { 
    translateService.addLangs(['en_gb', 'zh', 'en']);
    translateService.setDefaultLang('en');

    let browserLang =  translateService.getBrowserLang();
    browserLang = navigator.language;
    if (browserLang.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
      browserLang = browserLang.split('-')[0];
    }
    console.log('Language', browserLang);
    translateService.use(browserLang.match(/en|zh|en_gb/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let m;
    let n;
    const isIEOrEdge = /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
    if ( isIEOrEdge ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success(headers) {
        let language = headers['Accept-Language'];
        m = language.split(',');
        n = m[0].toString();
        if (m[0].indexOf('-')) {
          m[0] = m[0].split('-');
          n = m[0][0].toString();
        }
        console.log(typeof(n));

    }
});
  setTimeout(() => {
  this.useLanguage(n);
}, 3000);

} else {
    let browserLang = navigator.language;
    if (browserLang.indexOf('-') !== -1) {
      browserLang = browserLang.split('-')[0];
    }
    this.useLanguage(browserLang);
  }
  }

  useLanguage(language: string) {
    console.log('Language called:', language);
   // this.data.addNewTabWithCanvas(language);
    this.translateService.use(language);
  }
```

Comment: Where are the terms that aren’t translated?

Comment: all the terms in the button text i.e button text  {{filemenu.name}} , {{filemenu.edit}} and {{filemenu.view}} they are not getting translated. the moment i remove mat-button they get translated.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same actually.
It's probably the way the mat-button body is used internally and using `translate` directive didn't help. I had to use `translate` pipe for every text inside `mat-button` buttons. For example:

```
<button mat-button>{{ fileMenu.name | translate }}</button>
```

Comment: martin:  Did you made any changes in the .ts file also ? because where we should point the text to be translated

Comment: No, you don't need to change anything. Make sure that the translation really exist for example by calling `TranslateService.get` manually in a component.

Comment: can you give a demo example as my component file have everything and i have given code also can you lemme know where to change . ? It will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution just by adding this in my code

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="file" [hidden]="isFullScreen">**<span [translate] = "'FILE.MENU_FILE'">{{fileMenu.name}}</span>**</button>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="edit" [hidden]="isFullScreen"><span [translate] = "'EDIT.MENU_EDIT'">{{editMenu.name}}</span></button>
  <button mat-button [hidden]="isFullScreen" > <span [translate] = "'VIEW.MENU_VIEW'">{{viewMenu.name}}</span></button>
```

i.e adding span in the button tag will solve this issue